# How to get all the pod that are killed by OOMKilled in AKS Log Analytics?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-log-analytics

I have a kubernetes cluster in Azure (AKS) with the log analytics enabled. I can see that a lot of pods are being killed by OOMKilled message but I want to troubleshoot this with the log analytics from Azure. My question is how can I track or query, from the log analytics, all the pods that are killed by the `OOMKilled` reason?

Thanks!

Comment: from the doc it seems like it using Prometheus metrics, so i think `kube_pod_container_status_last_terminated_reason by (reason)` should give the list

Answer (score 2):

The reason is somewhat hidden in the `ContainerLastStatus` field (JSON) of the `KubePodInventory` table. A query to get all pods killed with reason `OOMKilled` could be:

```
KubePodInventory 
| where PodStatus != "running"
| extend ContainerLastStatusJSON = parse_json(ContainerLastStatus)
| extend FinishedAt = todatetime(ContainerLastStatusJSON.finishedAt)
| where ContainerLastStatusJSON.reason == "OOMKilled"
| distinct PodUid, ControllerName, ContainerLastStatus, FinishedAt
| order by FinishedAt asc
```