# Azure Kubernetes Service - Find Logs for Pods Killed for OOM

Tags: azure, kubernetes, out-of-memory, azure-aks, azure-diagnostics

I am running my k8s cluster on Azure Kubernetes Service. Recently I faced an Issue where one of my Pods was killed by Kubernetes because it breached memory (my assumption). I am trying to find an entry in AzureDiagnostics or in any other table to what caused the Pod killing/crash.

I have tried many KQL queries, but do not see any entries. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you need to enable container insights first: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-onboard

Comment: @4c74356b41: It is enabled for me. I checked the the config already.

Comment: well then you have to search container insights tables, not azurediagnostics

Comment: Any specific table - I have 4 tables
ContainerImageInventory, ContainerInventory, ContainerLog, ContainerNodeInventory, ContainerServiceLog. I tried in almost all the tables.

Comment: I tried "ContainerLog" with prper time generated and containerID, but it does not show why it was killed.

Comment: ContainerInventory should show reason killed, ContainerLog shows stdout

Comment: ContainerInventory - Does not help much. Just shows container status. Not the reason.

Answer (score 0):

- Please note that OOM might have happened due to the reasons mentioned below,

1. The memory that is being allocated to your pod is not enough.

   Please open your deployment.yml and increase the memory limits.
2. Sometimes the developers might be controlling the amount of memory that needs to be used. Speak to your developer if they have set such kind of limits
3. Check the logs of your ingress controller. When the ingress controller doesn't get response in default time which is 60s the request will get timeout and there are chances that pod might get crashed due to that.

- We can also check with azure CLI to get more details about the Pod.

Cmd: Kubectl describe pod “pod name”
[image]

- In Azure portal in logs you can verify also verify CPU usage, view Prometheus and pod as mentioned in below images.

CPU Usage Percentage per min[image]

View Prometheus disk read metrics from the default kubernetes namespace as timechart.
[image]

Pod info View pod phase counts based on all phases: Failed, Pending, Unknown, Running, or Succeeded.
[image]

- You can also try this query which is mentioned in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74005249/how-to-get-all-the-pod-that-are-killed-by-oomkilled-in-aks-log-analytics) question it may helps .If you have several Pods and need to quickly determine which ones were killed by OOM, this query may be helpful.